# Function Vector Space and operations defined on it

Tags: functions, vector-spaces

How is $(af)(x)$ different from $a(f(x))$, or how is $(f+g)(x)$ different from $f(x)+g(x)$?

Intuitively, I understand that those relations need to be equal (because of the definition of vector sum and vector scaling), but I can't visually imagine with the functions from Calculus I. Ex: if I consider $f(x)=ax^2$ and $g(x)=bx^2$, then $f(x)+g(x)=ax^2 + bx^2$. If I consider $(f+g)(x)$ then I can't intuitively think of anything different from $ax^2 + bx^2$. Should I think of the latter as $(a+b)x^2$? In this case how would you think of other functions like exp or ln: $f(x)=e^x$, $g(x)=ax^2$; in this last example I ultimately can't think of anything different from $e^x + ax^2$.

Thx in advance

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So... you don't say what kind of functinos you are considering, but let's assume that you are considering functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

What is a vector space? Remember that a vector space is really four pieces of information:

1. A set $\mathbf{V}$ of objects we will call *vectors.*
2. A field $\mathbb{F}$ of *scalars* (for the purposes of this answer, take it to be "the real numbers".
3. A rule for "adding" vectors: given two vectors $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2\in\mathbb{V}$, how to get a vector that we will call $\mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_2$.
4. A rule for "scaling" vectors: a way to take a scalar $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}$, a vector $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbf{V}$, and combine them to obtain a vector we call $\alpha\mathbf{v}$.

These sets and rules must then satisfy the usual 8 axioms to ensure you have a vector space.

In this example, the set $\mathbf{V}$ consists of the functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

So I need to tell you how to add two functions. If $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I want to describe a function that I will call $f+g$.

How do I describe a function? By telling you the domain, the codomain, and how to calculate it any point in the domain.

So I say: if $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, the function $f+g$ is the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that takes the number $a$ to the sum of the values of $f$ at $a$ and of $g$ at $a$. That is, $(f+g)(a)$ is *defined* to be equal to the number $f(a)+g(a)$.

It would be like saying:

> If $f$ and $g$ are functions, then their "sum" is the function $h$ whose value is $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.

Similarly, if $\alpha$ is a scalar and $f$ is a function, I need to tell you who the function $\alpha f$ is. To do that, I tell you that it is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and I also need to tell you how to calculate it at any real number. The rule is: to find the value of $\alpha f$ at the number $a$, find the value of $f$ at $a$, and multiply *that* by $\alpha$. That is, $(\alpha f)(a)$ is *defined* to be equal to the number $\alpha(f(a))$.

So: $(f+g)$ is the name fo the function. $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ tells you how to calculate the function $(f+g)$, assuming you know how to calculate $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. The left hand side of the equation is the value of a function at a single point. The right hand side tells you how to compute it using values of $f$ and of $g$. Likewise with $\alpha f$.

Comment: thx for the quick response and for the clear explanation, really helpful

Comment: @SimoneValigi: If you think the answers are helpful, be sure to upvote them (if you can; depends on your reputation). Once you are satisfied with an answer to your question, don't forget to "accept it" by clicking on the checkmark. You can only mark one answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

> How is (a*f)(x) different from a*(f(x)), or how is (f+g)(x) different from f(x)+g(x)?

Strictly speaking, they're ***not*** different, because is how they're defined.

Formally, when we speak of $af$, we're trying to perform scalar multiplication. Scalar multiplication requires two inputs: a scalar, and a vector (a function in this case). Moreover, scalar multiplication needs to output a function, and so we need to define what $af$ even means as a function. Luckily, we have a very natural "common sense" definition that holds.

Same with addition. We need to be able to take in two vectors (functions) and get another vector (function) out. What $f+g$ really ***means*** needs to be defined, but luckily there is a natural "common sense" definition to use.

But *a priori* we need to really define what these additions and multiplications mean, because ultimately they are just functions, but sometimes they can be very weird functions. (For example, modular arithmetic does not use the "standard" definitions of $+$ and $\cdot$, so we have to carefully define what they mean before we can even speak of their respective sets as having scalars, and everything derived from that.)

So, in order to make sure everything is perfectly well-defined and unambiguous, we ***define*** scalar multiplication and addition of functions by the rules given: that if $a$ is a scalar and $f$ a function, then their scalar multiplication $af$ is another function, such that
$$
(af)(x) := a f(x)
$$
and if $g$ is a function, then the sum $f+g$ is another function, defined by the rule
$$
(f+g)(x) := f(x)+g(x)
$$

Comment: ok I think I understand it better, thx